# Django отображаемое имя для NULL поля

Tags: django

Есть такой код

```
#models.py 
class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors, null=True, blank=True)
```

Как сделать, чтобы в случае, когда author == NULL запрос Books.objects.all() значение author выводил не None, а нужный мне текст?

Comment: В template делайте проверку и  вписывайте то что вам нужно

Comment: так это придется делать в каждом template, где используется Book. Хотелось бы это один раз как-нибудь обозначить, что если author == NULL, то выводить такую-то строку.

Comment: Ну либо производить во вьюхе проверку и присваивать то что вам нужно

Comment: а как? из вьюхи в шаблон передается список объектов Books. И если я пытаюсь `Books.author = 'Не известен'`, то получаю исключение `ValueError: Cannot assign "'Не известен'": "Books.author" must be a "Authors" instance.`

Comment: Перегнать в словарь все объекты, которые у вас есть, и в случае если у вас полe равно None, то полю присваивать пустую строку

Comment: @ivan K. спасибо, всё элементарно, что-то не подумал про такое :)

Comment: Только учитывайте что перегнать и возвращать надо только те объекты которые нужно вам отобразить, чтоб не делать лишних действий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поковырял мануалы, решение, оказывается, намного проще. Есть стандартный фильтр `default_if_none`. Используется в шаблоне следующим образом:

```
{{ book.author|default_if_none:"Не известен" }}
```

Если автор указан, то будет выведен он, если не указан, то выведется "Не известен".

Answer (score 0):

2 варианта решения:

- 1 В template делайте проверку и вписывайте то что вам нужно
- 2 Производить во вьюхе проверку и присваивать то - что вам нужно, предварительно перегнав в словарь все необходимые объекты

Comment: В итоге сделал так. Фильтр `def nonetostr(value): if value is None: return  'Не указано' return value` и в template юзаю его.

Comment: Неплохое решение